# Google maps in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, google-maps

What is the best/easiest way to integrate google maps and silverlight?  I would like to display a google map within a silverlight canvas, where the canvas will be surrounded by other silverlight controls that drive the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to use Google maps inside your Silverlight application and you can run your application in out of browser mode then you might want to [take a look at the WebBrowser control for Silverlight 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.WINDOWS.CONTROLS.WEBBROWSER);k(VS.XAMLEDITOR);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22SILVERLIGHT%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22)&rd=true)

Using the WebBrowser control, you could get started with something as simple as this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <WebBrowser Source="http://maps.google.com/" />
</Grid>
```

However, it's certainly not the best way to integrate mapping into a Silverlight application. To use mapping inside Silverlight your best choice is really the Bing Maps Silverlight control - take a look at these links to get started:

http://www.microsoft.com/maps/

http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/silverlight/

Answer (score 3):

There is no Silverlight control for Google maps. Google also only allows use of their map data if you are using their API. The path of least resistance will be to use Bing Maps with the Bing Maps Silverlight control.

Otherwise, you'd probably want to use a different web technology with javascript to integrate with Google maps.